# Active Record foreign key association rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, foreign-keys, associations, primary-key

I have the following models (venmas is a legacy database so I can't change it):

```
models/venmas.rb
class Venmas < ActiveRecord::Base
  establish_connection "turnkey"
end

models/yard.rb
class Yard < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

I want to be able to do:

```
Yard.first.venmas.first # to get the first record of venmas for that yard
```

Here is what Yard looks like:

```
#<Yard id: 1, name: "nyssa", created_at: "2012-08-07 16:58:02", updated_at: "2012-08-07 16:58:02">
```

and Venmas:

```
#<Venmas VENDOR_NUMBER: "  ", ... , yard: "nyssa"> # there are a lot of columns in this one and they aren't important.
```

One other monkey wrench I have this in inflections.rb:

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections do |inflect|
  inflect.irregular 'venmas', 'venmas'
end
```

I can remove this if it makes it easier, but I do this with all the legacy tables because I just read from them.

I am sure this can be done by assigning the foreign_key, but I am not really sure the right way to associate these?

Please let me know if there is anything that I am missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out

```
models/venmas.rb
class Venmas < ActiveRecord::Base
  establish_connection "turnkey"
  belongs_to :yard, foreign_key: :yard, primary_key: :name
end

models/yard.rb
class Yard < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :venmas, foreign_key: :yard, primary_key: :name
end
```

Still open to better solutions...